# Findviewby id cannot find Button

Tags: java, android

i'm very new in android programming so i have a little bit simple problem!
i created a  `button`   in   `activity_main.xml`   and in   `main_activity.java`   i want to use this button by calling   `findbyviewid()`    but when i write it,it can't find my button in   `activity_main.xml!`      this is the code:
    package com.example.test;

```
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.app.Activity;
import android.view.Menu;

public class MainActivity extends Activity {

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
        Button b=findViewById(R.layout.button1);//this is where i get error message that can't find my button

    }

    @Override
    public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
        // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
        getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.main, menu);
        return true;
    }

}
```

so what is my problem?

thanks!!!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try this:

```
Button btn = (Button)findViewById(R.id.button);
```

`findViewById` will return a View object, you have to downcast it into Button object.

Answer (score 1):

You need to find the id of the button inside the layout.

```
Button b=(Button)findViewById(R.id.button1);
```

Assuming that your layout `activity_main` contains :

```
<Button
   android:id="@+id/button1"
   /*****/
/>
```

You may find this [tutorial](http://www.mkyong.com/android/android-button-example/) useful.

Answer (score 0):

Typecast it to Button class first and it should be `R.id.button1` instead of `R.layout.button1`

```
Button b=(Button)findViewById(R.id.button1)
```

Answer (score 0):

Chanage to

```
Button b=(Button) findViewById(R.id.button1);
```